# How to print Function's I/P parameter as variable in C

Tags: c, function

Suppose I have:

```
func1()
{
    int var = something;
    func2(var);  /* Call func2() with var as I/P parameter */
    ......
    ......
}

func2 (int var)
{
   .....
}
```

We can use `__FUNC__` to print the name of `func2` in traces.

But is there any way to print `(inside f2())` the variable NAME used in the calling function (i.e. `f1()`) to call this function:

Something in traces (inside `f2()`) like:

```
func2(var)
```

Comment: The correct identifier is lowercase: `__func__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could modify the function to stringify the input:

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_PARAM_TRACE
    #define func2(a) _func2(a, #a)
#endif

#ifdef INCLUDE_PARAM_TRACE
    void _func2(int a, const char * param_string)
#else
    void func2(int a)
#endif
```

However, this can quickly turn rather messy unless you take very good care of how and where you define your methods :-)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such standard macro provided by c standard.
You will need to check the doccumentation of your compiler if it provides any such macro as an extension.
Note that even if you find one for your compiler, using it would mean your code is not portable accross compilers.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `__func__` between different functions

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f2(int v, const char *parent) {
  printf("value from %s is %d\n", parent, v);
}

void f1(void) {
  f2(42, __func__);
}

int main(void) {
  f1();
  return 0;
}
```

See code running at ideone: https://ideone.com/faGfT

Answer (score 0):

No.  Consider that the parameter might not even have a name:

```
func2(5 + 6);
```